Extermely slow Faster R-CNN training and memory usage increase every epoch
I am currently training Faster R-CNN algorithm with Mobilenetv2 as backbone. My own dataset is used, which approximately 9k images inlcuding train and valid set.
Initially, the training process goes smoothly, but one epoch takes 30 minutes, which is slow as I need to train with 200 epochs. After a few epochs, I found that the memory usage kept increasing in every epoch and finally Pycharm crashed (I checked the memory usage in Task Manager). I was wondering if there was some problem in the code like dataloader. 
The information below is my device specifications and parameters used in training:
GPU: RTX3050ti
RAM: 32GB
Windows: 10
Epochs: 200
Num_workers: 8
Batch: 16
Step_size: 50
Optimizer: SGD
And this is the python libraries version I installed:
Python : 3.7
torch: 1.7.1+cu110
torchvision: 0.8.2+cu110
torchaudio: 0.7.2
Below is the train.py of the Faster R-CNN used:
import os
import datetime

import torch
import torchvision

import transforms

# from memory_profiler import profile, memory_usage

from network_files import FasterRCNN, AnchorsGenerator
from backbone import MobileNetV2, vgg
from my_dataset import VOCDataSet
from train_utils import GroupedBatchSampler, create_aspect_ratio_groups
from train_utils import train_eval_utils as utils



def create_model(num_classes):
    # Uncomment to use VGG16 as the backbone
    # vgg_feature = vgg(model_name="vgg16", weights_path="./backbone/vgg16.pth").features
    # backbone = torch.nn.Sequential(*list(vgg_feature._modules.values())[:-1])  # Remove the last Maxpool layer
    # backbone.out_channels = 512

    # Using MobileNetV2 as the backbone
    backbone = MobileNetV2(weights_path="./backbone/mobilenet_v2.pth").features
    backbone.out_channels = 1280  # Set the output channels of the backbone

    anchor_generator = AnchorsGenerator(sizes=((32, 64, 128, 256, 512),),
                                        aspect_ratios=((0.5, 1.0, 2.0),))

    roi_pooler = torchvision.ops.MultiScaleRoIAlign(featmap_names=['0'],  # Feature layers for ROI pooling
                                                    output_size=[7, 7],  # Output size of ROI pooling
                                                    sampling_ratio=2)  # Sampling ratio

    model = FasterRCNN(backbone=backbone,
                       num_classes=num_classes,
                       rpn_anchor_generator=anchor_generator,
                       box_roi_pool=roi_pooler)

    return model


def main():
    device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    print("Using {} device training.".format(device.type))

    # File to save COCO evaluation results
    results_file = "results{}.txt".format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"))

    # Check if save_weights directory exists, create if not
    if not os.path.exists("save_weights"):
        os.makedirs("save_weights")

    data_transform = {
        "train": transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()]),
        "val": transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()])
    }

    VOC_root = "./"  # Root directory for VOC dataset
    aspect_ratio_group_factor = 3
    batch_size = 16
    amp = False  # Use automatic mixed precision training

    # Check if VOC root directory exists
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(VOC_root, "VOCdevkit")):
        raise FileNotFoundError("VOCdevkit does not exist in path:'{}'.".format(VOC_root))

    # Load training dataset
    train_dataset = VOCDataSet(VOC_root, "2012", data_transform["train"], "train.txt")
    train_sampler = None

    # Use aspect ratio grouping to reduce memory usage
    if aspect_ratio_group_factor >= 0:
        train_sampler = torch.utils.data.RandomSampler(train_dataset)
        group_ids = create_aspect_ratio_groups(train_dataset, k=aspect_ratio_group_factor)
        train_batch_sampler = GroupedBatchSampler(train_sampler, group_ids, batch_size)
    else:
        train_sampler = torch.utils.data.RandomSampler(train_dataset)

    num_workers = min([os.cpu_count(), batch_size if batch_size > 1 else 0, 8])  # Number of workers
    print('Using %g dataloader workers' % num_workers)

    if train_sampler:
        train_data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset,
                                                        batch_sampler=train_batch_sampler,
                                                        pin_memory=True,
                                                        num_workers=num_workers,
                                                        collate_fn=train_dataset.collate_fn)
    else:
        train_data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset,
                                                        batch_size=batch_size,
                                                        shuffle=False,
                                                        pin_memory=True,
                                                        num_workers=num_workers,
                                                        collate_fn=train_dataset.collate_fn)

    # Load validation dataset
    val_dataset = VOCDataSet(VOC_root, "2012", data_transform["val"], "val.txt")
    val_data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val_dataset,
                                                  batch_size=16,
                                                  shuffle=False,
                                                  pin_memory=True,
                                                  num_workers=num_workers,
                                                  collate_fn=val_dataset.collate_fn)

    # Create model
    model = create_model(num_classes=5)
    model.to(device)

    scaler = torch.cuda.amp.GradScaler() if amp else None

    train_loss = []
    learning_rate = []
    val_map = []

    # Freeze backbone and train the RPN and prediction head
    for param in model.backbone.parameters():
        param.requires_grad = False

    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD([p for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad],
                                lr=0.005, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.0005)

    init_epochs = 5
    for epoch in range(init_epochs):
        mean_loss, lr = utils.train_one_epoch(model, optimizer, train_data_loader,
                                              device, epoch, print_freq=50,
                                              warmup=True, scaler=scaler)
        train_loss.append(mean_loss.item())
        learning_rate.append(lr)

        coco_info = utils.evaluate(model, val_data_loader, device=device)

        with open(results_file, "a") as f:
            result_info = [f"{i:.4f}" for i in coco_info + [mean_loss.item()]] + [f"{lr:.6f}"]
            txt = "epoch:{} {}".format(epoch, '  '.join(result_info))
            f.write(txt + "\n")

        val_map.append(coco_info[1])

    torch.save(model.state_dict(), "./save_weights/pretrain.pth")

    # Unfreeze backbone and train the entire network
    for name, parameter in model.backbone.named_parameters():
        split_name = name.split(".")[0]
        if split_name in ["0", "1", "2", "3"]:
            parameter.requires_grad = False
        else:
            parameter.requires_grad = True

    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD([p for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad],
                                lr=0.005, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.0005)
    lr_scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=50, gamma=0.33)
    num_epochs = 200

    for epoch in range(init_epochs, init_epochs + num_epochs, 1):
        mean_loss, lr = utils.train_one_epoch(model, optimizer, train_data_loader,
                                              device, epoch, print_freq=100,
                                              warmup=True, scaler=scaler)
        train_loss.append(mean_loss.item())
        learning_rate.append(lr)
        lr_scheduler.step()
        coco_info = utils.evaluate(model, val_data_loader, device=device)

        with open(results_file, "a") as f:
            result_info = [f"{i:.4f}" for i in coco_info + [mean_loss.item()]] + [f"{lr:.6f}"]
            txt = "epoch:{} {}".format(epoch, '  '.join(result_info))
            f.write(txt + "\n")

        val_map.append(coco_info[1])

        if epoch >= (init_epochs + num_epochs - 5):
            save_files = {
                'model': model.state_dict(),
                'optimizer': optimizer.state_dict(),
                'lr_scheduler': lr_scheduler.state_dict(),
                'epoch': epoch}
            torch.save(save_files, "./save_weights/mobile-model-{}.pth".format(epoch))

    # Plot loss and learning rate curve
    if len(train_loss) != 0 and len(learning_rate) != 0:
        from plot_curve import plot_loss_and_lr
        plot_loss_and_lr(train_loss, learning_rate)

    # Plot mAP curve
    if len(val_map) != 0:
        from plot_curve import plot_map
        plot_map(val_map)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Finally, this is the first epoch I get during training, it takes 30 minutes to finish even the cuda is used for training.
Using cuda device training.
Using [0, 0.5, 0.6299605249474366, 0.7937005259840997, 1.0, 1.2599210498948732, 1.5874010519681994, 2.0, inf] as bins for aspect ratio quantization
Count of instances per bin: [7888]
Using 8 dataloader workers

Epoch: [0]  [  0/493]  eta: 3:10:50.930041  lr: 0.000015  loss: 2.3496 (2.3496)  loss_classifier: 1.6119 (1.6119)  loss_box_reg: 0.0329 (0.0329)  loss_objectness: 0.6825 (0.6825)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.0223 (0.0223)  time: 23.2270  data: 9.6419  max mem: 2793
Epoch: [0]  [ 50/493]  eta: 0:29:50.711795  lr: 0.000523  loss: 0.4996 (1.1243)  loss_classifier: 0.1341 (0.5352)  loss_box_reg: 0.0311 (0.0369)  loss_objectness: 0.2995 (0.5273)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.0349 (0.0248)  time: 3.6610  data: 0.0000  max mem: 3401
Epoch: [0]  [100/493]  eta: 0:25:17.636046  lr: 0.001030  loss: 0.2707 (0.7559)  loss_classifier: 0.0866 (0.3344)  loss_box_reg: 0.0200 (0.0356)  loss_objectness: 0.1424 (0.3629)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.0216 (0.0231)  time: 3.6545  data: 0.0000  max mem: 3401
Epoch: [0]  [150/493]  eta: 0:21:41.925717  lr: 0.001538  loss: 0.4117 (0.6141)  loss_classifier: 0.1599 (0.2656)  loss_box_reg: 0.0621 (0.0357)  loss_objectness: 0.1666 (0.2903)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.0232 (0.0225)  time: 3.6502  data: 0.0001  max mem: 3401
Epoch: [0]  [200/493]  eta: 0:18:23.093898  lr: 0.002046  loss: 0.2504 (0.5403)  loss_classifier: 0.0935 (0.2300)  loss_box_reg: 0.0295 (0.0369)  loss_objectness: 0.1117 (0.2515)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.0158 (0.0219)  time: 3.6510  data: 0.0002  max mem: 3401
Epoch: [0]  [250/493]  eta: 0:15:09.790380  lr: 0.002553  loss: 0.4560 (0.4929)  loss_classifier: 0.1365 (0.2058)  loss_box_reg: 0.0711 (0.0380)  loss_objectness: 0.2080 (0.2275)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.0403 (0.0216)  time: 3.6640  data: 0.0000  max mem: 3401
Epoch: [0]  [300/493]  eta: 0:12:01.483949  lr: 0.003061  loss: 0.3157 (0.4603)  loss_classifier: 0.0782 (0.1881)  loss_box_reg: 0.0362 (0.0400)  loss_objectness: 0.1764 (0.2110)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.0249 (0.0212)  time: 3.7164  data: 0.0001  max mem: 3401
Epoch: [0]  [350/493]  eta: 0:08:55.447698  lr: 0.003569  loss: 0.2501 (0.4348)  loss_classifier: 0.0756 (0.1733)  loss_box_reg: 0.0413 (0.0411)  loss_objectness: 0.1147 (0.1992)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.0185 (0.0212)  time: 3.7268  data: 0.0001  max mem: 3401
Epoch: [0]  [400/493]  eta: 0:05:48.394548  lr: 0.004076  loss: 0.2758 (0.4132)  loss_classifier: 0.0661 (0.1615)  loss_box_reg: 0.0446 (0.0420)  loss_objectness: 0.1335 (0.1889)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.0315 (0.0208)  time: 3.7426  data: 0.0001  max mem: 3401
Epoch: [0]  [450/493]  eta: 0:02:40.654559  lr: 0.004584  loss: 0.2503 (0.3963)  loss_classifier: 0.0699 (0.1520)  loss_box_reg: 0.0491 (0.0429)  loss_objectness: 0.1125 (0.1808)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.0188 (0.0206)  time: 3.6161  data: 0.0001  max mem: 3401
Epoch: [0]  [492/493]  eta: 0:00:03.726008  lr: 0.005000  loss: 0.2180 (0.3838)  loss_classifier: 0.0727 (0.1454)  loss_box_reg: 0.0495 (0.0436)  loss_objectness: 0.0839 (0.1744)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.0118 (0.0203)  time: 3.6157  data: 0.0000  max mem: 3401
Epoch: [0] Total time: 0:30:37 (3.7265 s / it)

creating index...
index created!
Test:   [  0/124]  eta: 0:21:36.053664  model_time: 3.1140 (3.1140)  evaluator_time: 0.0030 (0.0030)  time: 10.4520  data: 7.2820  max mem: 3401
Test:   [100/124]  eta: 0:00:52.285159  model_time: 0.7686 (2.0934)  evaluator_time: 0.0070 (0.0057)  time: 1.8716  data: 0.0001  max mem: 3401
Test:   [123/124]  eta: 0:00:02.106653  model_time: 0.2362 (2.0335)  evaluator_time: 0.0029 (0.0076)  time: 1.8302  data: 0.0000  max mem: 3401
Test:  Total time: 0:04:21 (2.1087 s / it)
Averaged stats: model_time: 0.2362 (2.0335)  evaluator_time: 0.0029 (0.0076)
Accumulating evaluation results...
DONE (t=0.48s).
IoU metric: bbox
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.012
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.046
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.75      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.002
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = 0.014
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=  1 ] = 0.033
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets= 10 ] = 0.109
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.119
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100 ] = 0.003
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = 0.131

Epoch: [1]  [  0/493]  eta: 1:42:49.210967  lr: 0.005000  loss: 0.2061 (0.2061)  loss_classifier: 0.0567 (0.0567)  loss_box_reg: 0.0293 (0.0293)  loss_objectness: 0.1100 (0.1100)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.0100 (0.0100)  time: 12.5136  data: 8.2839  max mem: 3401

I checked the train.py and it just train on my dataset normally.
I also tried to invalidate caches and restart the Pycharm several times to run the code, the problem still exist which are slow training problem and Memory usage gradually increase per epoch. I wish to know whether there is the problem in the code.
